# G++ and clang++ incompatibility with standard library when building shared libraries?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, compiler-bug

If I have a file clang.cpp containing:

```
#include <map>
void myfunc() {
    std::map<int, int> mymap;
    const int x = 20;
    myfoo[x] = 42;
}
```

and main.cpp containing:

```
void myfunc();
int main() { myfunc(); }
```

compiling `clang++ -g clang.cpp -shared -fPIC -o libclang.so -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++11` and `clang++ -g main.cpp -L -Wl.,-rpath=. -lclang -lstdc++ -o a.out -stdlib=libstc++ -std=c++11` will run fine.

However, if I add gcc.cpp containing:

```
#include <tuple>
template std::pair<int const, int>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<int const&>, std::tuple<>);
```

then also compile that to a shared library using `g++ -g gcc.cp -shared -fPIC -o libgcc.so` and change the linking command to `clang++ -g main.cpp -L -Wl.,-rpath=. -lgcc -lclang -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++11 -o a.out`, then running `./a.out` will segment fault.

I don't know what to make of this, since clang and gcc are supposed to be ABI compatible when using the same c++ standard library. My versions are 3.6.2 for clang, 5.2.1 for gcc, as shipped with ubuntu.

Comment: Since you're only declaring the specialization in one source file/translation unit this smells like an ODR violation.

Comment: The template is instantiated in in both units: `myfoo[x] = 42` is where this get instantiated in the `clang.cpp` file.  The way you get this in a realistic scenario is when `gcc.cpp` includes `unordered_map.h` and you have code similar to `clang.cpp` in that file.

Comment: So you're saying that `main.cpp` also includes `gcc.cpp` to pick up the specialization?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear -- `libclang.so` and `libgcc.so` will contain the specialization. Also, the ODR doesn't apply to instantiated template (multiple definitions are allowed as long as they are token for token equivalent)

Comment: You aren't allowed to do that. You can't just inject a specialization by linking against it. Every file in the final project must know that it's specialized at compile time or you violate the one definition rule (one specialized, one non-specialized).

Comment: @MarkB It's not an explicit specialization; it's an explicit instantiation. Those are fine.

Comment: GCC and Clang do pass `tuple<const int &>`s differently.

Comment: There is currently a large discussion on the ABI of passing empty types by value. It could be related.

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
int f(std::tuple<const int &> t){
  return std::get<0>(t);
}
```

Clang generates

```
f(std::tuple<int const&>):                    # @f(std::tuple<int const&>)
        movl    (%rdi), %eax
        retq
```

while GCC generates

```
f(std::tuple<int const&>):
        movq    (%rdi), %rax
        movl    (%rax), %eax
        ret
```

In other words, Clang is expecting the tuple itself to be passed by register, while GCC is expecting the address to be passed in register (and the tuple passed on the stack).

Mix and match and you get "fun" results.

Comment: Shorter example: `struct Tuple { int a; Tuple(Tuple&&); };
int f(Tuple t){
    return t.a;
}`

Comment: I am quite convinced that the bug is in clang (though the ABI could be clarified for C++11), it would be good if someone could report it there...

Comment: Discussion is going on here: http://sourcerytools.com/pipermail/cxx-abi-dev/2016-February/002884.html