# GCC/Clang x86_64 C++ ABI mismatch when returning a tuple?

Tags: c++, tuples, x86-64, abi, compiler-bug

When trying [to optimize return values on x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25381736/3919155), I noticed a strange thing. Namely, given the code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

constexpr uint64_t a = 1u;
constexpr uint64_t b = 2u;

pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> f() { return {a, b}; }
tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> g() { return tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t>{a, b}; }
```

[Clang 3.8 outputs](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-O2',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4IGcAudyYHwBQoksiqmMADlAocdPMijJiFCJgJ6EEzrgBzJGACGAWwTpKIiMixwA3AQIQA9mCwIAHpQBOSGLgBsAFgD6mJCKQBeJAEYYStRsza9B4%2BcsAjW0gAmJ2VpEF1mLwsAGk8wTFMLPCQAMwAKAEokAG8kXQQKXTBskRifAF8FJDKCCmoECLiEzBjDRu8kgQzs3PyYQqRamgb47xbI/CySpHLK6oIsEVYIMxF0dARdTFT%2BAC8EVTTQ8NaR6NjT/HSCJBvbu7ubO139tJOmzIBqJGeD1LfvdIxABEQPSSgWSxWaw2Wx%2BaUG9X%2BZyRl2u93RN0e3xAe1%2BR2GTTGbUSgKQILBQAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3) this assembly code for `f`:

```
movl $1, %eax
movl $2, %edx
retq
```

and this for `g`:

```
movl $2, %eax
movl $1, %edx
retq
```

which look optimal. However, when [compiled with GCC 6.1](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-O2',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4IGcAudyYHwBQoksiqmMADlAocdPMijJiFCJgJ6EEzrgBzJGACGAWwTpKIiMixwA3AQIQA9mCwIAHpQBOSGLgBsAFgD6mJCKQBeJAEYYStRsza9B4%2BcsAjW0gAmJ2VpEF1mLwsAGk8wTFMLPCQAMwAKAEokAG8kXQQKXTBskRifAF8FJDKCCmoECLiEzBjDRu8kgQzs3PyYQqRamgb47xbI/CySpHLK6oIsEVYIMxF0dARdTFT%2BAC8EVTTQ8NaR6NjT/HSCJBvbu7ubO139tJOmzIBqJGeD1LfvdIxABEQPSSgWSxWaw2Wx%2BaUG9X%2BZyRl2u93RN0e3xAe1%2BR2GTTGbUSgKQILBQAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3), while the generated assembly for `f` is identical to what Clang output, the assembly generated for `g` is:

```
movq %rdi, %rax
movq $2, (%rdi)
movq $1, 8(%rdi)
ret
```

It looks like the type of the return value is classified as MEMORY by GCC but as INTEGER by Clang. I can confirm that linking Clang code with GCC code such code can result in segmentation faults (Clang calling GCC-compiled `g()` which writes to wherever `%rdi` happens to point) and an invalid value being returned (GCC calling Clang-compiled `g()`). Which compiler is at fault?

### Related:

- [G++ and clang++ incompatibility with standard library when building shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35586332/3919155)
- [[cxx-abi-dev] Non-trivial move constructor](http://sourcerytools.com/pipermail/cxx-abi-dev/2016-February/002884.html)

### See also

- [System V Application Binary Interface. AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement. Draft Version 0.99.5](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)

Comment: Isn't `movl` 32 bit and `movq` 64-bit !?

Comment: @DieterLücking: Doesn't matter for positive integer constants less than or equal to `UINT32_MAX`, the upper 32-bit of the register are implicitly set to zero.

Comment: @DieterLücking The `movl` instruction clears the rest of the bits in the 64-bit destination register. Its just that the instruction encoding is 1 byte shorter in than the equivalent using `movq`.

Comment: @jotik: 2 bytes shorter.  The REX version of the 5byte `movl $imm32, %r32` encoding is the 10 byte `movabs $imm64, %r64` (REX + opcode + 8byte immediate).  The sign-extending `movq $imm32, %r/m64` form is 7 bytes:  It needs a mod/rm byte instead of encoding the dest register into the opcode.  (So it can store to memory, like `movq $2, (%rdi)` is doing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As davmac's answer shows, the libstdc++ `std::tuple` is trivially copy constructible, but not trivially move constructible. The two compilers disagree on whether the move constructor should affect the argument passing conventions.

The C++ ABI thread you linked to seems to explain that disagreement:
http://sourcerytools.com/pipermail/cxx-abi-dev/2016-February/002891.html

In summary, Clang implements exactly what the ABI spec says, but G++ implements what it was *supposed* to say, but wasn't updated to actually say.

Comment: I might be missing something, but, in the thread you link the suggested ABI text is:  _In the special case where the parameter type does not have both a trivial destructor and at least one trivial copy or move constructor that is not deleted, the caller must allocate space for a temporary copy, and pass the resulting copy by reference_ - which implies that `tuple` need not be passed by invisible reference, surely, since it is trivially movable and destructible? G++ is certainly not following that.

Comment: (edit: it is trivially _copyable_ and destructible.)

Comment: On re-reading, the text I quoted in the comment above is (IIUC) a suggested improvement to the "rule we ended up with" (but which never made it into the spec), and what you refer to by "what it was _supposed_ to say" is the latter and not the former. Ok, makes sense.

Answer (score 10):

The ABI states that parameter values are classified according to a specific algorithm. Relevant here is:

> 3. If the size of the aggregate exceeds a single eightbyte,  each is classified separately. Each eightbyte gets initialized to class NO_CLASS.
> 4. Each field of an object is classified recursively so that always two fields are considered. The resulting class is calculated according to the classes of the fields in the eightbyte:

In this case, each of the fields (for either a tuple or a pair) are of type `uint64_t` and so occupy an entire "eightbyte". The "two fields" to be considered in each eightbyte, then, are the "NO_CLASS" (as per 3) and the `uint64_t` field, which is classified as INTEGER.

There is also, related to parameter *passing*:

> If  a  C++  object  has  either  a  non-trivial  copy  constructor  or  a non-trivial destructor, it is passed by invisible reference (the object is replaced in the parameter list by a pointer that has class INTEGER)

An object that doesn't meet those requirements must have an address, and therefore needs to be in memory, which is why the above requirement exists. The same is true for return values, though this seems to be an omitted in the specification (probably by accident).

Finally, there is:

> (c)  If the size of the aggregate exceeds two eightbytes and the first eight-byte isn’t SSE or any other eightbyte isn’t SSEUP, the whole argument
>   is passed in memory.

That doesn't apply here, obviously; the size of the aggregate is exactly two eightbytes.

On returning of values, the text says:

> 1. Classify the return type with the classification algorithm

Which means, as per above, that the tuple should be classifed as INTEGER. Then:

> 3. If the class is INTEGER, the next available register of the sequence
>      %rax, %rdx is used.

This is quite clear.

The only still-open question is whether the types are non-trivially-copy-constructible/destructible. As mentioned above, values of such type cannot be passed or returned in registers, even though the specification does not seem to recognize the problem for return values. However, we can easily show that the tuple and pair are both trivially-copy-constructible and trivially-destructible, using the following program:

Test program:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "pair is trivial? : " << is_trivial<pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> >::value << endl;
    cout << "pair is trivially_copy_constructible? : " << is_trivially_copy_constructible<pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> >::value << endl;
    cout << "pair is standard_layout? : " << is_standard_layout<pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> >::value << endl;
    cout << "pair is pod? : " << is_pod<pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> >::value << endl;
    cout << "pair is trivially_destructable? : " << is_trivially_destructible<pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> >::value << endl;
    cout << "pair is trivially_move_constructible? : " << is_trivially_move_constructible<pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> >::value << endl;

    cout << "tuple is trivial? : " << is_trivial<tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> >::value << endl;
    cout << "tuple is trivially_copy_constructible? : " << is_trivially_copy_constructible<tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> >::value << endl;
    cout << "tuple is standard_layout? : " << is_standard_layout<tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> >::value << endl;
    cout << "tuple is pod? : " << is_pod<tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> >::value << endl;
    cout << "tuple is trivially_destructable? : " << is_trivially_destructible<tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> >::value << endl;
    cout << "tuple is trivially_move_constructible? : " << is_trivially_move_constructible<tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> >::value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output when compiled with GCC or Clang:

```
pair is trivial? : 0
pair is trivially_copy_constructible? : 1
pair is standard_layout? : 1
pair is pod? : 0
pair is trivially_destructable? : 1
pair is trivially_move_constructible? : 1
tuple is trivial? : 0
tuple is trivially_copy_constructible? : 1
tuple is standard_layout? : 0
tuple is pod? : 0
tuple is trivially_destructable? : 1
tuple is trivially_move_constructible? : 0
```

This implies that GCC is getting it wrong. The return value should be passed in %rax,%rdx.

(The main noticable differences between the types is that `pair` is standard layout and is trivially move-constructible whereas `tuple` is not, so it's possible that GCC is always returning non-trivially-move-constructible values via a pointer, for example).

Comment: The OP links to a cxx-abi-dev thread where the effect of move-constructors on the ABI is discussed, and it's agreed that trivially-move-constructible should be considered, and so GCC is (I believe) doing the right thing for the libstdc++ `std::tuple`.