# Why do std::pair<long, long> and std::tuple<long, long> generate different code

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, abi

I'm expecting std::pair and std::tuple have the similar behavior. But it turns out that std::tuple generates worse asm code then std::pair.

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ri4M8z - gcc 10.0.0 nightly build, `-O3 -std=c++17`
compiling for the x86-64 System V ABI

```cpp
#include <utility>

std::pair<long, long> test_pair() {
    return { 1, 2 };
}
```

```
# returned in RDX:RAX
test_pair():
        mov     eax, 1
        mov     edx, 2
        ret
```

---

```
#include <tuple>
std::tuple<long, long> test_tuple() {
    return { 1, 2 };
}
```

```
# returned via hidden pointer, not packed into registers
test_tuple():
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], 2
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+8], 1
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
```

Those two functions both return two values. `test_pair` uses registers to store values which is expected; but test_tuple stores values on stack, which seems unoptimise. Why these two functions behave differently?

Comment: in which program did you test that?

Comment: One of them is trivially copyable, the other isn't, leading to special treatment in the ABI.  :(  The compiler doesn't have a choice here (other than modifying the C++ ABI).  Normally this goes away with inlining, but it will apply any time you return a tuple or pair.

Comment: std::optional is more strange. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/LQBYw2 gcc 9.1 tries to save stack frame which is unnecessary in my opinion. gcc 7.4 won't do it either. Is it a bug?

Comment: @JesperJuhl > make sure to build with your compilers optimizer enabled
Of course. See my attached link

Comment: [GCC/Clang x86_64 C++ ABI mismatch when returning a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37457443/995714)